# How to configure Nginx virtual host to run C++ programms with FastCGI?

Tags: c++, nginx

I want to create c++ web-site, I am on zero level. need to run my first c++ file using nginx + fastcgi

I have a compiled programm on c++ :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

   cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
   cout << "<html>\n";
   cout << "<head>\n";
   cout << "<title>Hello World - First CGI Program</title>\n";
   cout << "</head>\n";
   cout << "<body>\n";
   cout << "<h2>Hello World! This is my first CGI program</h2>\n";
   cout << "</body>\n";
   cout << "</html>\n";

   return 0;
}
```

compiled it so:

g++ 1.cpp -lfcgi -o hello

and put to a site directory: /var/www/f.ci/public/bin/hello

then started spawn process:

```
spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 -n /var/www/f.ci/public/bin/hello
```

nginx virtual host configuration is:

```
server
{
    listen  80;
    server_name     f.ci www.f.ci *.f.ci;
    root            /var/www/f.ci/public;

    location /
        {
        try_files   $uri $uri/  =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ 
        {
        try_files $uri =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

}
```

to be exact this is file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params :

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https if_not_empty;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
```

i restarted nginx when configured virtual host.
my server give me to download hello file when i type in browser:
f.ci/bin/hello
but do not display it's message

please how to configure server correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong port  "fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;"
change 9000 to 8000

"spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 -n /var/www/f.ci/public/bin/hello"
"fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;"

The port numbers must match.

Comment: ok. but does not work in my server. more: i deleted nginx from update.rc to speed up my comp. and other php5-fpm and mysql deleted too. when i want to try work wth my server i only do: service nginx start and then i type spawn command but does not work with correct port. what is wrong now?